# inherit from UIViewControllerFlowLayout: whither layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've made a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and overridden

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *) layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * layoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
    <change layout attributes here>
    NSLog(@"WE NEVER GET HERE");
    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

because I want to change where the header gets placed. That method never gets called, even though everything seems to work (I see the header where the flow layout wants it).

Anybody run into this? I know my custom class is being created, because I can breakpoint into other overridden methods. Just not this one. Can something be interfering with it?

Comment: Are you aware that `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` must return layout attributes for supplementary views?  Did you override `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` to return your preferred frame/bounds/center for your supplementary view?

Comment: @robmayoff: Oh. I was hoping that the super class' implementation of that would call layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind, and I could just override that. No deal, I guess.